# Display data from Azure SQL Instance in Azure Storage using change data capture (CDC)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, change-data-capture

first of all, it's my first experience working with Azure.

I have a task: Displaying (created\updated\ deleted ) entries from Azure SQL in handy view on Azure portal.

After a small investigation I've found out:
Finding changes in the database is handled by the "Change Data Capture" mechanism(CDC). I've used it and now I have separate tables with the changes.

The next step to resolve the initial task is to send this data to Azure portal.  I the internet I've found the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal)

As I understood we just load data to blob (create a container and upload to here) and it will be a simple csv or another format text file.
If you know the way how to upload data to blob, please share with me.

And the last step is showing this file contents in useful tables, where I can select the filter option for example.  How can I do this?

Comment: so you retrying to display the the data in azure portal or just export the data somewhere ?

Comment: Hello,
The main goal is to display the difference on azure portal. Above I described the algorithm and how I see him. Maybe already exists some solutions that can help to resolve this task.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what does `on azure portal` means for you ? you want to display data thourgh azure portal or just make the exported file to blob storage available thorugh azure portal ?

Comment: Yes, i want to display data thourgh azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can just preview the data once stored in Azure Blob Storage. Displaying can be done by using Power BI as you can simply connect the Blob Storage and display and analyze the data.

Refer [Access data from Azure Blob Storage using Power BI](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-access-data-from-azure-blob-storage-using-power-bi/).

Other side, loading data to Azure Storage account from Azure Managed Instance is given in the document you have shared.

You will be using Azure Data Factory. It is Azure's integration service highly used to copy data between two source.

To copy the data, you need to create **Linked Service** which will connect with your source data location. Then you will be creating **Dataset** which will hold your data which needs to be transferred.

**Same components you need to deploy for destination, i.e., Blob Storage.**

Lastly, you need `Lookup` activity to perform the task which will take your source and destination details and you will be copying the data as given in the shared tutorial.

Follow the tutorial from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal#create-a-data-factory).